# A problem about convergence in distribution to $N(0,1)$.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

> Let $(Y_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of  independents random variables such that $$\mathbb{P}[Y_{n}=1]=\mathbb{P}[Y_{n}=-1]=\frac{1}{2n}, \quad \mathbb{P}[Y_{n}=0]=1-\frac{1}{n}, \quad n \geq 1$$
> Let $S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}$ and prove that $$\frac{S_{n}}{n}\overset{a.s}{\to}0 \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{S_{n}}{\sqrt{\log(n)}}\overset{D}{\to}N(0,1)$$

**My approach:**
For the first part, it's to say prove that $\frac{S_{n}}{n} \overset{a.s}{\to} 0$ I think that since that for $n\geq 1$, we know that
\begin{eqnarray*}
Y_{n}=1 \implies \mathbb{P}[Y_{n}=1]=\frac{1}{2n}\\
Y_{n}=-1 \implies \mathbb{P}[Y_{n}=-1]=\frac{1}{2n}\\
Y_{n}=0 \implies \mathbb{P}[Y_{n}=0]=1-\frac{1}{n}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
other values is not possible. So, the support for $Y_{n}$ is $S_{Y_{n}}={-1,0,1}$. So, by definition we have $$\mathbb{E}Y_{n}=\sum_{y_{n}\in S_{Y_{n}}}y_{n}\mathbb{P}[Y_{n}=y]=\sum_{y_{n}\in \{-1,0,1\}}y_{n}\mathbb{P}[Y_{n}=y]=0$$
similarly, we have $$\mathbb{V}Y_{n}=\mathbb{E}Y_{n}^{2}-(\mathbb{E}Y_{n})^{2}=\frac{1}{n}$$
and since that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathbb{V}Y_{n}}{n^{2}}<\infty$, so by SLLN-Kolmogorov with have $$\frac{S_{n}-\mathbb{E}S_{n}}{n}=\frac{S_{n}}{n} \overset{a.s}{\to} 0$$
For the second part, to prove that $\frac{S_{n}}{\sqrt{\log(n)}}\overset{D}{\to} N(0,1)$ but don't have the hypothesis identical distribution, so I can't use the central limit theorem. **How can I solve this part?**

---

**Note:** I know that if $Y_{1},Y_{2},\ldots$ are independent random variables and let $\displaystyle S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{n}$. For each $i$ let $\mu_{i}=\mathbb{E}Y_{i}$ and $\sigma^{2}_{i}=\mathbb{V}Y_{i}$ and let $m_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu_{i}$ and $s_{n}^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sigma_{i}^{2}$ mean and variance respectively. Suppose that a) $s_{n}^{2}\to \infty \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty$ and b) there exists a constant $M$ sucha that $\mathbb{P}[|X_{i}|\leq M]=1, \forall i$. So we have $$\frac{S_{n}-m_{n}}{s_{n}}\overset{D}{\to}N(0,1)$$

Comment: the standard proof of central limit theorem is not that hard, involving transforms -- you can find it at Wikipedia under central limit theorem

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Proof_of_classical_CLT

Comment: @DanielS.I know the central limit theorem. I'm interesting in how can I solve part b) using the variation in central limit theorem without the hypothesis of identical distribution.

Comment: You could try finding the variance of the sum, and then using something like [Lindeberg's condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition).  If you want to prove it yourself, you may want to use characteristic functions, but it will not be easy.  $S_{Y_n}$ may not be helpful notation given that $S_n$ already means something different

Comment: @Henry Yes, I know that Lindeberg's condition. So, I found that expectation $\mathbb{E}Y_{i}=0 \implies m_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}Y_{i}=0$ also since that $\mathbb{V}Y_{i}=\frac{1}{i} \implies s_{n}^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{V}Y_{i}\to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: So, by that condition we have that $\frac{S_{n}-m_{n}}{s_{n}}\overset{D}{\to} N(0,1)$ But, I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: @Henry I added the characterization of central limit theorem without the hypothesis of identical distribution. But I don't know how can I use that result.the hypothesis a) I can check but the hypothesis b) I don't know how to prove that. Also, using that result I can find that $\frac{S_{n}}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}}}\overset{D}{\to}N(0,1)$.

Comment: @АлександрПальма You may want to use something like $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i} =\log(n)+\gamma +O(1/n)$ so between $\log(n)$ and $\log(n)+1$

Comment: I was thinking to use that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}=H_{n}$ where $H_{n}$ is the harmonic number and $\lim_¨{n\to \infty} \sqrt{H_{n}/\log(n)}=1$. So, we can see that $\frac{S_{n}}{\sqrt{H_{n}}}\sqrt{\frac{H_{n}}{\log(n)}}\overset{D}{\to}N(0,1)\cdot 1$. Is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the characteristic function of $S_n/\sqrt{\ln n}$ is given by
$$
\varphi_{S_n/\sqrt{\ln n}}(t)=\prod_{i=1}^n\left[\frac{\cos(t/\sqrt{\ln n})-1}{i}+1\right].
$$
Taking logs and noticing that $\ln(1+x)\approx x$ for small $x$, one gets,
\begin{align}
\ln\!\left(\varphi_{S_n/\sqrt{\ln n}}(t)\right)&\approx \left(\cos\!\left(t/\sqrt{\ln n}\right)-1\right)\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}\\
&=\left(\cos\!\left(t/\sqrt{\ln n}\right)-1\right)\ln n \times R_n\to -\frac{t^2}{2},
\end{align}
where $R_n\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$.

---

Alternatively, setting $g_n(t)=\cos(t/\sqrt{\ln n})$,
$$
\varphi_{S_n/\sqrt{\ln n}}(t)=\frac{\Gamma(g_n(t)+n)}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(g_n(t))}\approx \frac{n^{g_n(t)-1}}{\Gamma(g_n(t))}\to e^{-t^2/2},
$$
where we used the following approximation: $\Gamma(n+a)/\Gamma(n+b)\approx n^{a-b}$ for large $n$.

Comment: So,  $\frac{S_{n}}{\sqrt{\ln n}} \overset{D}{\to} e^{-t^{2}/2}$?

Comment: No. It's c.f. converges to $e^{-t^2/2}$, which means that $S_n/\sqrt{\ln n}\xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)$.

Comment: Oh, you're right. So, since that the c.f converge to $e^{-t^{2}/2}$ can I conclude that $N(0,1)$, is it correct?

Comment: Thank so much. I understand your answer. Congratulations for your answer.

Comment: By the way, the result follows from [Lévy’s continuity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem#:~:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20L%C3%A9vy's%20continuity,convergence%20of%20their%20characteristic%20functions.)